# Laravel: PHP Artisan Migrate throws PDO Exception: Could not find driver (Postgres)

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, nginx, pdo

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.10

**Server:** Nginx

**DB:** PostgreSQL 9.5.4

**Laravel 5.4**

Trying to perform my database migrations, but `php artisan migrate` throws the following error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   could not find driver: (SQL select * from information_schema.tables where tables_schema = username and table_name = migrations)

Followed by a second message stating

> [PDOException]
>
> could not find driver

I have done the following:

1. Verified that I have php-pgsql's latest version installed
2. Uncommented the line pertaining to php_pdo_pgsql.dll in /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
3. Restarted both posgtresql and nginx multiple times

Currently, when I run `php -i`, the output I get for the PDO section is

> PDO support => enabled
>
> PDO drivers => pgsql

The pdo_pgsql section yields

> PostgreSQL(libpq) Version =>9.5.4
>
> Module version =>7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.10.4

And the pgsql section returns

> PostgreSQL(libpq) Version = 9.5.4
>
> PostgreSQL(libpq) => PostgreSQL 9.5.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 6.1.1-11ubuntu12) 6.1.1 20160805, 64-bit Multibyte character 
>   support => enabled
>
> SSL support => enabled
>
> Active Persistent Links => 0
>
> Active Links => 0

But in spite of this, still getting the same error. I thought there was some chance it might be a permissions problem, but running the command as either root or www-data has the same result.

Comment: If you're using php-fpm you need to restart it, apart from restarting web server (nginx/apache)

Answer (score 6):

you should install PHP pdo

```
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo apt install php-pgsql
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been through the same situation, and do it in the following in order:

1. Install the postgre extensions for php, those are: `php-(YOUR_VERSION)-pgsql`, and `php-pgsql`.
2. Enable pgsql extensions in your php.ini file, basically, uncomment the extensions.
3. Restart the apache server (or nginx).
4. Check that extensions are enable using phpinfo() or any similar tool.
5. Set a password for (in instance) the postgres user in PostgreSQL server, this is a very important step.

Login to the psql shell:

```
sudo su - postgres
\password postgres
```

enter a password and confirm it.

Now, set your .env file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your .env file

in your.env file you need to specify which database are you using (MySQL, SQLite, Postgres) and specify your DB username and password

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:gqaCpjbEfukDr5As7EnrqRzi5PSho1rOS/q2H0E+HOs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=YOUR_DB_NAME
DB_USERNAME=YOUR_USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

And it is always good to run these commands when working with migrations

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: If you want I can help you over teamviewer, you probably made some small mistake, but it's always hard to tell what is wrong if you can't see

Answer (score 0):

My issue solved by simply installing `php-pgsql`

I'm using PHP v8.1 So i ran.

`sudo apt-get install php8.1-pgsql`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

**SOLVED:**

Make sure in this scenario that you have run

`php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache`

I thought I'd done this at every pivotal step, but running both of these commands again allowed me to conduct the migration and get the site running properly. Thank you to lewis4u for the assistance, however.